# Android OpenGL Multithreading in c++

Tags: android, c++, ios, multithreading, opengl-es

I am currently working on a heightmap in OpenGLES with C++ for mobile platforms. The problem is that I can't seem to find out, how I can get multithreading or asynchronous code to work in C++. I was wondering if someone knows how to make an asynchronous datarequest without blocking the main GLThread. Is it even possible in C++ or do I have to make the calls from another thread in Java or Swift?

Currently I am using libcurl to request tiles, but as I mentioned earlier, it is blocking the OpenGL thread. I would like to use RxCpp because I am already familiar with reactive programming, but my concern is that after hours of getting the library to work in cmake, I find out that it is not possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: C++11 `std::thread` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread And also __Threads__ here in the main docs https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work with std::async. My problem were the `get()` and `wait()` methods because they are blocking the main thread.